# How to transform a spherically-projected render into a perspective projection?

Tags: 3d, projection

Suppose that you have a projection obtained by mapping spherical coordinates to a texture; example:

[image]

1. What is that projection called?
2. Is it possible to "fix" such texture so that it becomes a regular perspective projection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That specific projection is called an equirectangular projection.
2. Your second question is much harder to answer. The short answer is "no" there isn't a "simple" way to fix this projection to a perspective projection. You can easily map it to a cube, but that's just due to how it's defined (you can find out more about this with a quick google search). As for a more difficult answer, if you need to create a perspective image from one of these projections, you'll have to do some more advanced edge and line detection. I found paper that talks about some methods, but it's still quite tricky.

[Face and Straight Line Detection in Equirectangular Images](http://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/43708922/wvc_2010_paper.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ56TQJRTWSMTNPEA&Expires=1471352994&Signature=CKKOE1KTNj%2BX3ocg24MslwQ6QSs%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DFace_and_Straight_Line_Detection_in_Equi.pdf)

Edit:

After a bit more research, I found that you can make a perspective projection by projecting each point on the sphere onto a cube that contains the sphere. Paul Bourke has a quick tutorial for photoshop which can probably be converted to pseudocode fairly easily.

[Paul Bourke - Spherical Panoramas](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/sphericalpano/)

Comment: So your original answer about edge detections was wrong, right? That is really cool. You nailed it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah, the edge detection paper was just about edge detection in spherical mapping systems. I believe Paul Bourke shows you how to just go from a spherical projection to perspective.